# Jquery Help Need For Div Height

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to get the auto height of my div, normally the div box its setup via css 160px but with overflow: hidden; how i can check the auto height its more then 160px or not via jquery ?

i need this because i have box what i have a button for Show More or Show Less so if the height its not bigger then normally height 160px to pass the command ... right now its making my box smaller

My code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#Show_More_Websites").click(function() {
  var Button_Value = $("#Show_More_Websites").attr("value");
  var Box_Height   = $('.Box_Show_Websites').outerHeight();

  if(Button_Value == "Show More") {
   if(Box_Height <= "160") {
    var el = $('.Box_Show_Websites'),
    curHeight = el.height(),
    autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height();
    el.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 500);
   }
   $("#Show_More_Websites").attr('value', 'Show Less');
  }

  if(Button_Value == "Show Less") {
   var el = $('.Box_Show_Websites'),
   curHeight = el.height(),
   autoHeight = el.css('height', '160px').height();
   el.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 500);


   $("#Show_More_Websites").attr('value', 'Show More');
  }
 });
</script>
```

**Update**

Here you can find my code: http://jsfiddle.net/rAjBH/

Comment: Could you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ sample ?

Comment: try using `$(element).offsetHeight`

Comment: i try but didn't work with that command Rohit Agrawal

Comment: in your code the autoheight is less then the height you given with css, so definately it will come smaller

Comment: because this i want to know how much its the autohight, i know the height in css its fixed (big or small) then the auto height, what i'm trying to do is if the auto height its small then css height to don't do nothing

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/rAjBH/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution

demo fiddles - *Note: the following fiddle has change in only html part to increase the autoheight using html `<br/>`*

> http://jsfiddle.net/rAjBH/1/ - autoHeight is less
>   http://jsfiddle.net/rAjBH/2/ - auto height is more

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#Show_More_Websites").click(function() {
  var Button_Value = $("#Show_More_Websites").attr("value");
  var el = $('.Box_Show_Websites')
  var Box_Height   = el.outerHeight();
  var autoHeight =  el.css('height', 'auto').height();
  el.css('height',Box_Height+'px');

  if(Button_Value == "Show More") {
    if(autoHeight > Box_Height) {
      el.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 500);
    }
    $("#Show_More_Websites").attr('value', 'Show Less');
  }

  if(Button_Value == "Show Less") {
    curHeight = el.height();
    autoHeight = el.css('height', '160px').height();
    el.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 500);
    $("#Show_More_Websites").attr('value', 'Show More');
  }
});
});
```